# Почему, если мы присваиваем переменной b (типа Integer) переменную a (типа int) программа работает, а если наоборот, выдаёт ошибку?

Tags: java, оператор-присваивания, int, примитивы

```
public class Smm extends Monster {
    int a;
    Integer b;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Smm smm = new Smm();
        smm.eat();
    }
    public void eat(){
        a=b;
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

потому что у примитива(`int`) значение по-умолчанию 0. А у "обертки"(`Integer`) - `null`.

А `null` нельзя присвоить примитиву

[Хорошее описание различий на хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/104231/)